# Making my function playback two sequences at the same time

Tags: c, function

This program is designed to be able to record and store melodies inputted by the user and then play back the sequences the user recorded. I have got two record functions of which the functions scan for an input from the user and then stores the note numbers and velocity into two seperate `.txt` files.

The program also has a metronome feature (function) and a tempo (int length) feature.

My program is running fine apart from I've just realised that it doesn't play the two sequences recorded back at the same time. In fact, it only plays the second sequence stored in "midinotes2.txt", this has left me confused and i cant seem to find a way to make both sequences play back together. Can anyone see what might be wrong with my code or what i could add to make it work?

```
#include "aservelibs/aservelib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
//------------------------------------------------function declarations
float mtof(int note, float frequency);
FILE play(void);
FILE record(void);
FILE record2(void);
int length();
void* metronome(void* param);
int playMetronome;
//------------------------------------------------main program
int main()
{
//------------------------------------------------variables

    FILE *textFilePointer;
    int counter = 0;
    char user;



//------------------------------------------------main menu
    do

    {

        printf("Press A to Record 1st Melody (A), B to Record 2nd Melody (B)\nP to Play Melodies (P) X to Exit (X):");
        scanf(" %c", &user);
//------------------------------------------------record 1st melody
        if (user == 'a' || user == 'A')
        {
            playMetronome = 1;
            pthread_t tid1;
            pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,metronome,0);
            textFilePointer = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "w");
            *textFilePointer = record();



            if(textFilePointer == NULL);
            {
                printf("Recording Complete\n");
                playMetronome = 0;

            }
            counter = 0;
        }
//------------------------------------------------record 2nd melody
        else if (user == 'b' || user == 'B')
        {
            playMetronome = 1;
            pthread_t tid1;
            pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,metronome,0);
            textFilePointer = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes2.txt", "w");
            *textFilePointer = record2();



            if(textFilePointer == NULL);
            {
                printf("Recording Complete\n");
                playMetronome = 0;

            }
            counter = 0;
        }

//------------------------------------------------plays the melodies back
        else if (user == 'p' || user == 'P')
        {
            textFilePointer = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "r");
            *textFilePointer = play();

            textFilePointer = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes2.txt", "r");
            *textFilePointer = play();

            if(textFilePointer == NULL);
            {
                printf("Playback Complete\n");
                aserveOscillator(0, 0, 0, 0);
                aserveOscillator(1, 0, 0, 0);

            }
            counter = 0;

        }
//-------------------------------------------------exits program
        else if (user == 'x' || user == 'X')
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    while(counter < 16);

}

//--------------------------------------------------function declarations

//--------------------------------------------------converts MIDI number to frequency
float mtof(int note, float frequency)
{
    frequency = 440.0 * pow(2, (note-69) / 12.0);
    printf("Playing Note:%d\n", note);



    return frequency;
}

//--------------------------------------------------changes tempo of sequence playback
int length()
{

    return (aserveGetControl(7)/((127.0 - 0) / (1000 - 100))) + 100;
}
//--------------------------------------------------metronome function
void* metronome(void* param)
{
    while(playMetronome)
    {
    aserveOscillator(3, 1500, 0.8, 0);
    aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);
    aserveSleep(length()*2);
    aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);

    aserveOscillator(3, 1000, 0.8, 0);
    aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);
    aserveSleep(length()*2);
    aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);

    aserveOscillator(3, 1000, 0.8, 0);
    aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);
    aserveSleep(length()*2);
    aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);

    aserveOscillator(3, 1000, 0.8, 0);
    aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);
    aserveSleep(length()*2);
    aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);


    }
    return 0;
}
//--------------------------------------------------playback function
FILE play(void)
{
    FILE*file;
    file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "r");
    file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes2.txt", "r");

    do {

        int note[2];
        int velocity;
        float freq[2];
        int frequency;
        fscanf(file, "%d, %d\n", &note[0], &velocity);
        fscanf(file, "%d, %d\n", &note[1], &velocity);
        freq[0] = mtof(note[0], frequency);
        freq[1] = mtof(note[1], frequency);
        aserveOscillator(0, freq[0], 1.0, 0);
        aserveOscillator(1, freq[1], 1.0, 0);
        aserveSleep(length()*2);
    } while (feof(file) == 0);


    return *file;
}


//--------------------------------------------------layer 1 record function

FILE record(void)
{
    int counter;
    FILE*file;
    file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "w");

    do
    {

        int note = aserveGetNote();
        int velocity = aserveGetVelocity();

        if (velocity > 0)
        {
            fprintf(file, "%d, %d\n", note, velocity);
            printf("Note: %d, Velocity: %d\n", note, velocity);
            counter++;
        }


    } while (counter < 16);
    fclose(file);
    return *file;
}

//--------------------------------------------------layer 2 record function

FILE record2(void)
{
    int counter;
    FILE*file;
    file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes2.txt", "w");

    do
    {

        int note = aserveGetNote();
        int velocity = aserveGetVelocity();

        if (velocity > 0)
        {
            fprintf(file, "%d, %d\n", note, velocity);
            printf("Note: %d, Velocity: %d\n", note, velocity);
            counter++;
        }


    } while (counter < 16);
    fclose(file);
    return *file;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `FILE play(void)`, you're assigning `file` first to the first file handle, then to the second one. So you're basically overwriting the variable.

```
file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "r");
file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes2.txt", "r");
```

So this is my guess why it would `play` the second file, but not the first one.

I can also tell you that your code is not very easy to read and does plenty of things which seem redundant (like reading files multiple times without actually using them, assigning variables without using them).
Have you debugged this code at some point ?

If not, you really should do that to make it easier to read and also more robust.